# nginx prevent loading from cache

Tags: php, nginx

I am updating my site frequently after finishing updates my clients reporting that old images & scripts are getting loaded instead of new ones. I know they are coming from their browser cache but is there any way i can force scripts not to load from cache in server.

I am using nginx with php-fpm.

Comment: You can try using headers like these: `header('Expires: Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can force HTTP headers to influence the browser caching behavior, however this is probably not a good idea in a production environment where you want caching.

So simply use something like:

```
expires -1
```

To force `Cache-Control no-cache` header

Check here for more information:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule

That being said, I have gotten myself in the habit of just changing image and static files names as I revise them.  Perhaps this comes from working with CDN's where this can be incredibly helpful.  So say I have static files that I might update often (i.e. they are not part of some specific piece of content).  I would name them like:

```
someimagev1.jpg
someimagev2.jpg
somejs1.js
somejs2.js
etc.
```

I change values (and links in HTML source) as needed.